# Does adding powers of $1/2$ based on coin flips produce an equal uniform distribution?

Tags: probability

Does this method of generating random numbers:

Start at $0$. Now follow the infinite steps:

1. flip a fair coin. If the result is heads, add ${2}^{-1}$
2. flip a fair coin. If the result is heads, add ${2}^{-2}$
3. flip a fair coin. If the result is heads, add ${2}^{-3}$
4. flip a fair coin. If the result is heads, add ${2}^{-4}$
5. ...

have a perfectly uniform random distribution between $0$ and $1$?

How can I prove it?

Comment: It's $1$ inclusive. All the flips may land as heads.

Comment: @StinkingBishop you're right

Comment: Did you try to use induction? After the first flip, it is independent of the rest of the flips. The rest of the flips combine to form uniform distribution also.

Comment: @Somos I don't see how to apply it here

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is uniform. Represent the numbers in the interval in binary, then your algorithm says that each bit has equal chance of being 0 or 1. So in any interval of the type $[j2^{-n},(j+1)2^{-n}]$ your number has a probability of $2^{-n}$ of lying in it, which is the length of that interval. Uniformity on sets of this type can be extended to all measurable sets in the interval.